# jQuery slideDown on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-animate, jquery-load

I am loading a a partialView using ASP.NET MVC in my jQuery code. The partialView contains some explanation about the item that is clicked in my click function, and I would like the explanation to slide down once the object is "loaded".

I have the following code:

```
$('.details').click(function(){ 
    $('#details').load($(this).data('url'), { id: $(this).data('id')}).slideDown('slow'); 
    //the slidedown part doesn't seem to work.
});
```

But the `.slideDown()` doesn't seem to work. How can I got about this? Should I use `.animate()` instead?

Thanks!

## EDIT

I found some questions saying I might need to `.hide()` it first. This seems to work, however it seems the "element" is not completely loaded when it slides down as some of the text updates after finishing the `.load()`.

Is there some way to run the `.slideDown()` once the load finishes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just because $().load() is not immediate. There is a third parameter that is a callback than runs when load is complete, so, you need to await to slide down (not tested, sorry).

Can you try this?
    $('#details').load($(this).data('url'), { id: $(this).data('id')}, function() { $(this).slideDown('slow'); });

and tell us if it works.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks! :D